# Import Json data into Core Data with the relationships

Tags: json, core-data, relationships

I have a model with two entities:

`Country` and `City`

Country has one attribue "countryname" and a "to many" relationship attribute called: "cities"

City has one attribute "cityname" and a "to many" relationship attribute called: "countries"

Country has a "to many" relationship with City as for 1 country there are more than 1 city.

I was able to import this prefilled Json file into my core data with also the relationships:

```
[{"CITY":"PARIS","COUNTRY":"FRANCE"},
{"CITY":"NICE","COUNTRY":"FRANCE"},
{"CITY":"NANCY","COUNTRY":"FRANCE"},
{"CITY":"BERLIN","COUNTRY":"GERMANY"}]
```

my problems is that inspecting the sqlite generated by the application I see Countries duplicates in the table `COUNTRY`, for example if I have four cities from France, I see 4 records "France" instead of one related to the 4 Cities.

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Each time you set relationship check to see if a particular object already exists. Like for each of the city object when you iterate over, check to see if the COUNTRY with the same name already exists in Context if yes set it to the relationship else create a new object.

Comment: yes, thanks for the answer, I was already thinking of it. Into the loop of the import I made a FetchRequest with Predicates to see if in the database there is a particular Country, and if so he set the relationship. it seems working now.